# positive expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorial-identities

Let 
$$a_{n,k}=\sum_{s_i \geq 1 \atop \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} s_i \leq n} \frac{2^{n}}{(2(n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} s_i)+1)!\prod_{i=1}^{n-k} (2s_i)! }$$
for $0 \leq k \leq n-1$. Prove for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ that
$$b_{n,k}=\sum_{l=1}^k (-1)^{k-l} \sum_{s_i \geq 1 \atop \sum_{i=1}^l s_i =k} \prod_{i=1}^l a_{n,s_i}>0.$$
Motivation and alternative formulation can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128835?sort=newest#sort-top)

Comment: Any chance that $b_{n,k}$ is an inclusion-exclusion summation?

Comment: Yes, it may be possible to interpret it as a inclusion-exclusion summation which would prove the positivity but I don't know how. The formula for $b_{n,k}$ comes from the condition
$$\sum_{i=0}^ka_{n,i}b_{n,k-i}=0$$

Comment: Forgot a $(-1)^i$ in the formula

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer on page 102 of
http://web.iitd.ac.in/~maz088121/chui.pdf